# (jQuery 1.8.2) load binding doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I coded a little script that load from another page some content into a tooltip div. After loading, I want to move the tooltip and manipulate it a little. To do so I want to wait the browser rendering. I coded something like this:

```
element.on("load", function (event) {
    /* some code */
    $(this).off(event);
});

element.load(url, function() {
    /* some code */
});
```

Result: tooltip is loaded, but the event is not fired.

http://jsfiddle.net/sUJrU/

Comment: According to http://api.jquery.com/on/, it seems that "In all browsers, the load, scroll, and error events (e.g., on an <img> element) do not bubble". I wonder if that is causing the lack of event firing.

Comment: "but they _can_ be used when the event handler is directly attached to the element generating the event". It remains to see what they means exactly with "_can_" PS: I'm using jQuery 1.8.2

Comment: But [the documentation page for the deprecated `load()` method](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) says `this event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object`. Is `element` an image, script, frame or window?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: No, it's a div! Thank you very very much. PS: is there a way to be informed about new answers on stackoverflow by mail? I already added an e-mail address.

Comment: @Lucas, not directly. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147957/get-an-email-when-there-is-activity-on-a-question.